# How to exit while loop with new value?

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

For one of my assignments, we are supposed to 1st generate a random number between 1 and 13, then we ask the user if they would like to draw another number. If they do, we are supposed to add another random number within 1-13 without going over 21. What I am stuck on is how I can exit the while loop after 1 new random number is added and asking the user if they would like to add another one. I tried using    break; This is what I have so far:

```
int randCard = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * ((13 - 1) + 1));
    int playerHand = 0 + randCard;
    System.out.println("START GAME #" + gameNum);
    System.out.println("Your card is a " + randCard + "!");
    System.out.println("Your hand is: " + playerHand);
    System.out.println("\n1. Get another card");
    System.out.println("2. Hold hand");
    System.out.println("3. Print statistics");
    System.out.println("4. Exit");
    System.out.print("\nChoose an Option: ");
    int selectedOption = menuOptions.nextInt();

 if (selectedOption == 1) {

             do {
                 int newRandCard = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * ((13 - 1) + 1));

                 System.out.println("Your card is a " + newRandCard + "!");
                 System.out.println("Your hand is: " + (playerHand + newRandCard));

                 playerHand = (playerHand + newRandCard);


                break;

             }
                 while (playerHand <= 21) ;

////////IDEALLY IT SHOULD PRINT LIKE THIS//////
Your card is a 4!
Your hand is: 4
1. Get another card
2. Hold hand
3. Print statistics
4. Exit
Choose an option: 1
Your card is a 9!
Your hand is: 13
1. Get another card
2. Hold hand
3. Print statistics
4. Exit
```

Comment: Put the asking within the loop. Logic would be -> while, player chose card (yes continue, no break), random card, add new card to stack, if stack goes
 over 21 break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If you only need it to add a random number once, then give the user the menu options again*

```
System.out.println("START GAME #" + gameNum);
int randCard = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * ((13 - 1) + 1));
System.out.println("Your card is a " + randCard + "!");
int playerHand = 0 + randCard;
System.out.println("Your hand is: " + playerHand);
do {
  System.out.println("1. Get another card");
  System.out.println("2. Hold hand");
  System.out.println("3. Print statistics");
  System.out.println("4. Exit");
  System.out.println("Choose an Option: ");
  int selectedOption = menuOptions.nextInt();

  if (selectedOption == 1) {
      randCard = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * ((13 - 1) + 1));
      System.out.println("Your card is a " + newRandCard + "!");
      System.out.println("Your hand is: " + (playerHand + newRandCard));
      playerHand = (playerHand + randCard);
  }
   ...other options to select
} while (playerHand <= 21) ;
```

Comment: if I don't use break, the program keeps adding a random number, I only need it to add a random number once, then give the user the menu options again.

Comment: i edited the post to what it should ideally print like.

Comment: you can put a `break;` on `selectedOption == condition` then

Comment: i tried the break; method inside the selectedOption == 4 but it keeps inside the loop. Where would the break go if it isn't inside there?

Comment: it would break out of the loop it is in...so in code as shared by me it would exit the do..while loop.

Comment: I just realized I had placed break inside the selectedOption==1. Sorry about that and thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code to the following to loop until the user makes a selection other than 1.

```
if (selectedOption == 1) {
     do {
         ...
     } while (playerHand <= 21 && selectedOption == 1);
```

Comment: Hey I just tried this and it stays inside the loop still. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to draw one card, then don't use the do-while cycle. Just use what's inside the do-while (whithout the break).

If you want to draw cards until the user tells you, then create a boolean variable and use it as a condition of the do-while cycle, and read it at the end of every cycle.